# CSS spread <li> horizontally across <ul>

Tags: css, html-lists

I'm trying to spread a list of `<li>`'s aligned horizontally using `float:left` across my `<ul>`.

Does anyone have any idea how this is done?

Comment: `float: left;` sounds good. What HTML/CSS do you have so far?

Comment: @Tomalak I was actually trying to divide them evenly, e.g. they will all have the same width regardless of their content, together adding up to the <ul>'s width.

Comment: best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11466521/104380

Answer (score 8):

Is there some reason why you can't just set them to `display: inline;` (or `inline-block`)?  For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TKmR5/

Comment: Display inline creates an awkward space between items, it also disallows to set width or height.

Comment: Then use `inline-block` instead! "awkward space between items" is caused by not re-setting margins and paddings…

Comment: I was able to figure out something similar myself, but this is not what I were looking after. I want differently sized items, but spread over a set width.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is to use `display: table;` on the `<ul>` element and `display: table-cell;` on the `<li>` elements.

Comment: Wow didn't even know this after all this time. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work, would be interested in seeing a codepen or fiddle to see what else was added to styling in order to get it to work this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block;` it works in modern browsers.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/joar/ELpDD/

As feela said in the comments to [#7131346](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131310/css-spread-li-horizontally-across-ul/7131346#7131346),

> […] "awkward space between items" is caused by not re-setting margins and paddings…

Answer (score 1):

Float left and divide the width of the `ul` over de number of `li`s I think is what you are after. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/b2nsW/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>item</li>
     <li>item</li> 
     <li>item</li> 
     <li>item</li> 
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

li {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    margin: 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: Working, but only useful, if you have a fixed number of menu-items. But a customer may add more menu-items via a CMS.

Answer (score 1):

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then adjust the padding or margins of the li elements to spread them across less or more across the ul.