# Spread dynamic menu on full page width

Tags: html, css

I got a dynamic horizontal menu. I am trying to make it always 100% of the page width.
So if there are 6 or 8 items or if I want to change the title of each item, I won't need to resize each item again.

The menu buit as a `<ul> <li>Item 1</li> <li>Item 2</li> ... </ul>` list. Please see how I would like it to be presented (attached image). Right now in my html the items ends before the full width.

Any ideas how to solve this ? I think if I would turn the menu into table it would fix this, but I preffer not to work with tables in this case.

You can see the website here: [enter link description here](http://www.neutrinoteam.com/clients/angiologist.com/)
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You should always try to post some code so we can see what you have tried already.

Comment: It's okay :) just want to try to help you.

Comment: Thnk :) I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So finally I found the solution for that. CSS only, no JS needed.
It's quite simple actually:

The wrapping `<ul>` should have:

```
display: table
```

The `<li>` itself should have:

```
display: table-cell
```

and remove it's float.

That's all :)

Comment: on IE7 you should leave the float for the <li>

Comment: the `UL` element should have a specific width, such as 100% alongside it being set to `display:table`

Answer (score 0):

If you would be comfortable using a javascript framework called jQuery you could use the following code...

See this jsfiddle as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BDVTP/

You'll need to include jquery if you aren't already (but it looks like you are)

Then use the following code:

```
 <script type="javascript/text">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var width = $('#access').width(); // width of the menu container
     var total = $('#menu-top-menu li').size(); //number of menu items
     $('#menu-top-menu').find('li').each(function(i){
         var border = parseInt($(this).css('border-left')); //border you have set
         $(this).width((width/total)-border); // calculate width and set it
     });​
 });
 </script>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Please note that this will **NOT** work if the items wouldn't fit in the first place - it basically adds more width.

Comment: Thanks. I actually think **there is** a solution without the need to involve jQuery/js . This solution might make the menu flicker when the page loads. I havn't test it yet, but I will try to find a solution with CSS alone, if not, I will try it.