# How to adjust menu width according to window width

Tags: html, css, viewport, navigationbar

I am designing `navigation menu`, but I couldn't adjust width according to window. I want to make `menu width 100%`, as we change the window size, the menu still covers from left corner to right corner.

The following code I am using for designing navigation:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="span9">
<!-- Menu-->
<ul id="menu" class="sf-menu">
    <li class=""><a href="index.html" class="sf-with-ul">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="work.html" class="sf-with-ul">WORK</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="blog.html" class="sf-with-ul">BLOG</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="tables_princing.html" class="sf-with-ul">FEATURES</a></li>                                                        
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
 <!-- End Menu-->
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.sf-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 7px;
}
.sf-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
.sf-menu > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Here the [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5dEAq/)

Comment: The question is very unclear. Could you explain more/better? Like what element do you want 100% width?

Comment: I want to make the navigation menu in such a way, so that it touch left and right corner even if I change the screen size.

Comment: @Ankit - I am not sure whether its the same you are looking for, but would you mind checking this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647178/spread-dynamic-menu-on-full-page-width , if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make width 100% for navigation menu bar. Try the following **CSS** for your HTML.

**CSS**

```
nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: none;
}
nav ul {
    display: table-row;
}
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Here the [JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5dEAq/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Setting a min-width to parent element will solve this issue. But still it might create a scroll or if you set overflow to hidden it will crop some text out. 
To prevent this scrolling / cropping you can use javascript or [css3 media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). I prefer media queries over javascript solution. But you may need css3 supported browser. 
Here is the modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chamathb/4gbcW/) with css media query

```
.sf-menu {
margin: 0;
padding-top:7px;}
.sf-menu > li {
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style: none;
line-height: 20px;
margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}
.sf-menu > li > a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
font-size: 17px;
}
@media all and (min-width:500px){
.sf-menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}    
.sf-menu > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
}
```