# Make li elements stack horizontally

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I need the following li to stack against each other in a horizontal fashion like so:

`*li1 *li2 *li3`

instead of:

```
 * li
 * li
 * li
```

Pretty much the li elements would be aligned like a gallery with the lis to the right being hidden and scrolled as needed.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnXDF/)

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131310/css-spread-li-horizontally-across-ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add another container that handles the scrolling of its content
- Make the `li` be `display: inline-block` so they'll stack next to each other
- Set `white-space: nowrap` on the `ul` so the `li` elements will stay on one line in its narrow container

http://jsfiddle.net/EvilOatmeal/nxGG2/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the `li` elements be `display:inline-block` and their container to be `white-space:nowrap`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/RnXDF/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="list">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

the css to accomplish what you want is

```
#list li{display:inline-block}
```

Comment: can you please use the JSFiddle I provided. Also I tried inline-block and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the width in .comments and then add display:inline-block to .comments li ,
It wasn't working because you are restraining the width of the list causing that when you try to display it horizontally there is not enough space to place it the

horizontally