# How to put li side by side in drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that the drop down menu's are side by side, instead of a list.. but for me to make that happen I'd have to remove the `position:absolute` from `#navigation > .nav-body > .menu > ul > li > .drop-ul` and that still won't do because it messes up all the code.. How can I make it side by side? I'd try jQuery but not sure how to.

```
<section id="navigation">
<div class="nav-body">  
    <section class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/"><span class="icon"></span>home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/"><span class="icon"></span>second</a>
                <ul class="drop-ul">
                    <a href="/guide-keto-diet">
                        <li>
                            sub 1
                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/">
                        <li>
                            sub 2
                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/">
                        <li>
                            sub 3
                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/">
                        <li>
                            sub 4
                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a href="/">
                        <li>
                            sub 5
                        </li>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/"><span class="icon"></span>cat 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: On a side note, [`a` is not a valid child of `ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), only `li` is. So your `a` tags should be inside of your `li` and optionally styled so they fill all of the space in the `li`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make li elements stack horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504454/make-li-elements-stack-horizontally)

Comment: Thanks for that, I searched all afternoon long for it and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently built a pure CSS drop-down menu for a website. It's similar to yours in structure. List items (`li`) are side by side. Code has passed [validation](https://validator.w3.org/) with no errors or warnings.

**HTML**

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="main-nav-sub">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2.5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="main-nav-sub">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
        <ul class="main-nav-sub">
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5.4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: absolute;
}

#main-nav > ul  > li {
    float: left;
    background-color: #000;
}

.main-nav-sub {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#main-nav > ul  > li+li {
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
}

.main-nav-sub > li  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: #000;
}

.main-nav-sub > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
}

#main-nav > ul > li > a,
.main-nav-sub > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#main-nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-nav-sub > li:hover > a {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.main-nav-sub {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -999;
    opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE older versions */
        zoom: 1;  /* IE older versions */
}

#main-nav > ul > li:hover > .main-nav-sub {
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* IE older versions */
        zoom: 1;  /* IE older versions */

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/x9upvtp0/

Comment: I hope this answer is helpful. Let me know if this is what you were looking for, otherwise I can revise my answer.

Comment: No, that was perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I was actually wondering how I could make it so that the drop down would only show when I hovered over the li, and not over the hidden drop down?

Comment: Nevermind, I simply used display:none and block instead of opacity that way the drop down only shows if you hover over the first list.

Comment: It's resolved, the only issue I am having now is that the drop down menu isn't centered after I hover it.. any ideas? Would you like me to put the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is the trouble that I am having now.. http://jsfiddle.net/soojj0zc/1/ the drop down isn't centered when hovered.. or the last drop down, shouldn't go over the width.. the last menu should flow towards the left so that it doesn't go out of the screen.. know what i mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90136/discussion-between-michael-b-and-ibrazilian2).